# Nexus6p or Samsung galaxy note4 device showing image small

Tags: android, image, screen-density

i am fetching some images from server where image resolution is about 150x150 and i am showing into imageview my imageview width and height are wrapcontent its shows in some device like sony xperia e4  as expected i.e default image width and height 150x150 which server provided me but in nexus6p and Samsung galaxy note4 device whose resolution about 1440x2560 560dpi those device show me small image its not maintaining aspect ratio of image so what is happening there or wrong there how to maintain image aspect ratio to all of device screen.my imageview parameters are as following.please help me to resolve this issue. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Post your layout file so we can see what you're doing wrong.

Comment: if you set your layout to wrap_content, images are going to be smaller on high res devices. But there's another mistake in your layout if the aspect ratio is off.

Comment: so what i have to do to maintain aspect ratio of image to all of screen device my imageview parameters are as following what changes required into imageview.

Comment: <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/img1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                      />

Comment: please do not down vote

Comment: Scale type should be FitXY I think. But if your imageview isn't keeping aspect ratio it's probably the result of the rest of your layout file (the image view's containers). Also, to get the image to look relatively the same on all devices you need to remove "wrap_content" for your width and height and give it a size in DP.

Comment: so,are you sure that by giving size of width and height of imageview it will maintain image aspect ratio to all of screen of device

Comment: please remove down vote i have showed layout to you

Comment: The aspect ratio has more to do with the scaletype. Also, fitXY might not be the correct one. setting the width and height will ensure that the view looks that size across different devices.

Comment: Thanks for your answer i got it.

Comment: please remove down vote requested you if possible.thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consider `wrap_content`as "take as much space as needed".

say you have two 5 inch devices. one  is 480 x 640  and the other is 1080 x 1920.
now you can understand that a image with dimension 150 x 150 pixel will look smaller in second device simply because second device has higher pixel per inch so 150 will take less space in second device(which is also the reason to use `dp` in android and not `px`).

Answer (score 0):

Wrap_Content would make your imageView small/big based on mobile screen's resolutions.
If you want to show images adjustable to all screens, set the width and height of imageview in DPs.

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/img1" android:layout_width="150dp" android:layout_height="150dp" android:layout_gravity="center" android:scaleType="fitXY" android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

You can change the 200dp values in case you want them bigger/smaller.